# Invert fn key without going to BIOS

Tags: toshiba-laptop, fn-key

I need to invert my Fn key on my Toshiba Satellite, but all the other answers included going to the BIOS.  I don't know how to go there, and I don't want to risk damaging the computer.  Is there a way to invert the Fn key without going to BIOS?  Thanks.

Comment: Which model is it? Is there a function lock key somewhere? If you see a key labelled FnLk, press that while holding the function key to invert the function key. Otherwise, maybe this will help: https://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD2503B90001R01.htm

Comment: Umm... I threw away the box a long time ago so I don't know what model it is.

Comment: And with regards to the website, I have a Windows 10 not 7, so there is no HWSETUP program.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this: http://support.toshiba.com/sscontent?contentId=4007069 then see if the "Toshiba function key" software is usable on your laptop. http://support.toshiba.com/drivers

Comment: @JackThomas Check "Windows Mobility Center", it may contain the option for inverting the Fn key.